# Can we use same OAuth bearer token from different machine for API call

Tags: oauth, token

Suppose i am calling webapi from my machine in angular  and get token from server, can i call api from other machine using same token will server be able to authenticate it.

Answer (score 1):

Bearer token allows any party in possession of the token to use it. Using a bearer token does not require the bearer to prove the possession of token. However API implementation may add another layer checking, like one time use only, or bind token to first calling client.